# Fifa 15 (or older) - Does an online career mode for two friends playing one team exist?

Tags: fifa-14, fifa-15

A very good friend and I had a play routine over the last 5 years. One of us purchased FIFA for the PC. Then one visited the other and we played together. We always started a normal offline career mode and played the same team in coop. We had a lot of fun with managing our team, playing together to reach our goals over usually more than 10 seasons. We did this for thousands of matches and always restarted when a new fifa came out.

Sadly, this good friend of mine now has to move to a city several hours from here, so we can't play in this kind of way any more. My question is now (since I never really played fifa online). Is it (maybe in the newest FIFA 15, but maybe also in olders?) possible that I (owning fifa) start a career mode and he can join me somehow and play with me in my team (over multiplayer, if he also buys a copy of the game)? So I DON'T want a league where I play a team and my friend plays another. I want that we decide on one team and we both play it (the matches, fulfill the tactical decisions etc.) Just like in an "offline" career mode.

I did a lot of google research but could not find yes or no information so far (maybe not many people play the game in the way we do it - cooperatively)

I hope my question is well formulated, if you have any open questions regarding it I'd be happy to respond.

Edit: If this counts, we usually played on the PC

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at least to my knowledge, there is no Online Career Mode for FIFA 15, nor have there been in any previous FIFA installments.

There are however a couple of Online (PvP) modes that support co-operative play. One of which is Pro Clubs, in which, you and a number of friends create a team. The players in this team comprise of AI and Virtual Pros (which is basically a player you create). In this game mode you take on other people's teams in an attempt to reach Division 1. You can also compete in cup events that happen once or twice a month.

The other game mode is Co-Op Seasons, in which you and a friend (I think this is limited to one other player only, not sure though) play as any team on the game, and you play against another co-op team playing as another team. The aim is the same as Pro Clubs, in which you try and reach Div 1, along with the optional cup windows.

In both game modes, Matchmaking is customised according to what Division your team is in; so people in Div 10 wont be put against people in Div 3 for example. And in Co-Op Seasons, Matchmaking is also calculated against the team you select's star rating; so you won't get Accrington Stanley vs Barcelona for example.

More information on [Pro Clubs](http://www.easports.com/uk/fifa/news/2014/fifa-15-pro-clubs-and-other-modes) and [Co-Op Seasons](http://www.easports.com/fifa/news/2013/fifa-14-co-op-seasons-first-look)

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility to play a co-op online career mode is on the Playstation 4. The next update gives people the opportunity to share their screen live with friends. You can let your friend take over controll of play at the same time. 
Fifa 15 and Fifa 14 has online co-op seasons and pro clubs which you can play together.